# Add time series to existing data frame

Tags: r, join, append, time-series

I am attempting to add a times series column to an existing data frame.  However my code adds all time into one column (left to right) instead of top to bottom.

```
 N<-5
 pacsub <- data.frame((seq(1, N, 1)))
 colnames(pacsub) <- c("Subject")
 pacsub
 pacwk<-data.frame(seq(0, 8, 1))
 colnames(pacwk) <- c("Week")
 pacsub$Week <- rep(pacwk, times = N)
 pacsub
```

Comment: To further explain, I want to look at 8 weeks of time data for each subject

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do: `pacsub<-data.frame(Subject=rep(1:N, each=9), Week=rep(0:8, N))`.

Comment: Your results look like what I need but your code appears to create the database along with adding the time series.  What I am desiring to do is to add a time series to an existing data frame....I already have a df with subjects and want to add a time series for each subject

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "create the database". Can you show samples of (1) what your starting data frame looks like, and (2) what you expect the data frame to look like when you're done?

Comment: pacsub in the in original post R script is the starting data frame.  I want to add a time series such that the final result looks like:
Subject    Week
1  1
1  2
1  3
1  4
1  5
1  6
1  7
1  8
2  1
2  2
etc

Comment: Response did not show properly. Will repost proper output

Comment: Original data frame will look like:N<-5
    pacsub <- data.frame((seq(1, N, 1)))
    colnames(pacsub) <- c("Subject")
    pacsub.  Final data frame is to look like data <- function(ids,time_vec) {
  obs.data <- data.frame(expand.grid(ids,time_vec),Week=0) 
  names(obs.data) <- c("ID","Week")
  obs.data<-obs.data[order(obs.data$ID),]
  return(obs.data)
}
test<-data(ids=1:5, time_vec= seq(0,8,1))
test<-test[c(1,2)]

Comment: Okay. If initial data frame you load looks like this: `pacsub <- data.frame(Subject=seq(1, N, 1))`. Then all you need (I think) is `pacsub = merge(pacsub, data.frame(Week=0:8)); names(pacsub)[grep("Subject",names(pacsub))] = "ID"`. Unless you have already have a separate pre-existing data frame with the `Weeks`. Then just merge that. You could also do `pacsub = expand.grid(ID=unique(pacsub$Subject), Weeks=0:8)`.

Comment: A couple additional notes: You can assign column names right in the call to `data.frame` or `expand.grid` (as I do in my examples above), rather than needing separate lines of code to assign names. Also, since `data` is already and R function, it's probably better to call your own functions or other objects by a different name.

Comment: Thank you.  Both work very well.  Yes assigning columns names in the call to data.frame sure makes it easier and more efficient